# Shutdown / hibernation timer that blocks powersave functions such as standby

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, hibernate, timer

I used to use [Vista Shutdown Timer](http://www.vistashutdowntimer.toflo.de/) to put my machine into planned hibernation. However, it does not block powersave function of my power plans such as standby after certain time etc. Hence, sometimes it may happen that my systems goes into standby before even being hibernated through the timer.

Do you now any timer that brings this functionality?

Comment: i am not sure about this but use this command in command prompt: shutdown /s /t <time in seconds>....I am not sure whether it overrides hibernation and standby...just check

Comment: Sorry I corrected my start post. I need a timer to hibernate but still blocking powersave functions. As far as I know there is no inbuilt Windows tool for hibernation.

Comment: Have you tried the Advanced Power Settings to turn off sleep functions and hibernate after a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [Don't Sleep](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/DontSleep). It does exactly what you want.

[image: Don't Sleep Screenshot]

#### Info from developer's website:

> Don't Sleep is a small portable program to prevent system shutdown, Standby, Hibernate, Turn Off and Restart.
>
> But not only that, it also prevents loggin off the computer, and the deactivation of the monitor or activation of the screen saver.
>
> Apart from the fact Don't Sleep has a timer that allows time control unblock, or shutdown the computer for a specified time.
>
> Don't Sleep does not have to be installed and can be executed easily from the desktop, and can be carried on a small usb-stick or other memory device.

Donwload Don't Sleep from http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/DontSleep

Comment: Thank you Alex. I came across this little program already earlier but did not pay attention to its feature to stop blocking and hibernate. Originally I thought this application is only capable of blocking the powersave functions.